# Can you land on the "real" 404 page without a direct link?

Tags: support, 404-not-found

As for question title, I am wondering if it is possible to actually land on the 404 page for a site (example: https://meta.stackexchange.com/404 ) without manually typing the actual link.

As far as I know, if you try to visit a not-existing page you do indeed see the 404 page message, but you are ***not*** redirected to the page, so the visited URL still is the one you tried to access.

I know the final effect is quite close, but I am asking this to evaluate the possibility of an unwanted behavior.

Answer (score 4):

I had never visited that direct link, but I got the hat within the first hour on Information Security. I had been viewing comment links, and I'm pretty sure one was a deleted comment. I went to the /404 to get it on the main SO site.

[The "Oops!" page](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/62836) triggers counts for the Not Found hat of 2022 Bash. I confirmed by going to a bad link to a comment. I suspect the link is for a comment on a deleted question or answer.

Comment: 1) what badge did you get for visiting the /404 page? 2) You can go to https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/error to see the error page, no need to find something that's really broken on the site.

Comment: /404 gave me Not Found (https://www.project3851.com/data/not-found.svg)

Comment: I assume you mean the hat (for Winter Bash), not the badge.

Comment: @V2Blast yes, thanks, edited.